# Convert Quill Editor generated HTML to simple HTML using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: html, sql, oracle, plsql, quill

I have to convert **Quill Editor** rendered list to **simple HTML** using **PL/SQL.**

There is a sample HTML generated by quill editor :

> <ul>
>  <li>Parent</li>
> <li>Parent</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-1">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-1">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-2">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-2">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-2">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-3">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-3">Child</li>
>  <li
> class="ql-indent-1">Child</li>
>  </ul>

I want to convert this to :

> <ul>
>           
>  <li>Parent</li>
>           
>  <li>Parent
>           
>  <ul>
>                    
>     <li>Child</li>
>           
>              <li>Child
>     
>                    <ul>
>                          
>        <li>Child</li>
>        
>                          
>  <li>Child</li>
>              
>                    
>  <li>Child
>                 
>                    <ul>
>                          
>                 
>  <li>Child</li>
>              
>                          
>        <li>Child</li>
>        
>                          
>  </ul></li>
>              
>           </ul></li>
>     
>        <li>Child</li>
>        
>     </ul></li>
>  </ul>

which is equivalent to the below list :

```html
    <ul>
      <li>Parent</li>
      <li>Parent
        <ul>
          <li>Child</li>
          <li>Child
            <ul>
              <li>Child</li>
              <li>Child</li>
              <li>Child
                <ul>
                  <li>Child</li>
                  <li>Child</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

> The **ql-indent-n** is limited to **n=50**.

How can this be converted using PL/SQL ?

I am using Oracle.

Comment: Can you get `<li class="ql-indent-42">Child</li>` or is there a maximum depth that the indent will go to?

Comment: There is no limit.But the text box is limited to 4000 characters , so it will not go to that depth.

Comment: However, `<ul><li>Parent</li><li class="ql-indent-9999999999999">Child</li></ul>` is only 70 characters.

Comment: Not at all , for ql-indent-9999999999999 we need 9999999999998 ql-indent-* items

Comment: That is not specified in your question; I am assuming then that Quill will only increase the indent by 1 each time?

Comment: Let us assume for 50 items , i.e. ql-indnet-50